# Confirmation popup

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

How to display confirmation popup?

I have <kbd>Close window</kbd> button and I want to show confirmation `Popup` before actually closing window.

Currently it's done like this

```
        <Button x:Name="ButonExit" Content="Close window">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PopupExit" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="True"/>
                            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
        <Popup x:Name="PopupExit" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=ButonExit}" StaysOpen="False">
            <TextBlock>Here will be some text and buttons</TextBlock>
        </Popup>
```

Which is awkward if you ask me:

- name button (to assign child to popup - `PlacementTarget`);
- name popup (to set its property `IsOpened` from animation);
- create button event trigger with storyboard and single frame of `BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames` animation.

Can't it be something like

```
<Button Content="Close window" OnClick="OpenTehPopupPlx"\>
```

Comment: Why not just spawn popup window from the code using Command?

Comment: @TzahMama, to let designer to deal with `Popup` in `Blend` (in some future).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course you can use code behind if you want. MVVM doesn't mean no code-behind, it means only use code-behind to drive UI appearance, not logic, and even then only if doing so via XAML is not simpler.

Your case is clearly easier to drive using code-behind for a simple confirmation dialog. Any more complex logic in the dialog would require interaction with the VM though, and you'd need to have some kind of dialog service that the VM could talk to.

Comment: I haven't tested `Blend` yet (I am using VS express), yet I can presume it wouldn't be good to have popup *out of style*. That's why `Popup` is inside xaml and that's why I am trying to avoid any coding.

Answer (score -1):

Make a function to show the popup and call it whenever you click the button.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).